# python .os.path.walk with direct file

Tags: python

Everything in the `/home/username/main/books/` directory gets written and returned, but `/home/username/main/index.html` does not get written because "index.html" is not a directory and therefore cannot be walked. How would I revise the script to say if its a directory, walk it then write everything it finds, and if its direct file, write it.

python

```
def zipit (request):
  file_paths = ['/home/username/main/books/', '/home/username/main/index.html']
  buffer= StringIO.StringIO()
  z= zipfile.ZipFile( buffer, "w" )
  for p in file_paths:
    for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(p):
      for f in files:
        filename = os.path.join(dir, f)
        z.write(filename, arcname = filename[15:])
  z.close()
  buffer.seek(0)
  final = HttpResponse(buffer.read())
  final['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=dbs_custom_library.zip'
  final['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-zip'
  return final
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check `p` before walking.

- If it is a directory => walk in.
- If it is not => just add this file to the archive.

Modified code:

```
def zipit (request):
  file_paths = ['/home/username/main/books/', '/home/username/main/index.html']
  buffer= StringIO.StringIO()
  z= zipfile.ZipFile( buffer, "w" )
  for p in file_paths:
    if os.path.isdir(p):
      for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(p):
        for f in files:
          filename = os.path.join(dir, f)
          z.write(filename, arcname = filename[15:])
     else:
          z.write(p, arcname = p)
  z.close()
  buffer.seek(0)
  final = HttpResponse(buffer.read())
  final['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=dbs_custom_library.zip'
  final['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-zip'
  return final
```